# Tagging EC2 machines in Pipeline's EMR Cluster (ImportCluster in the S3->DynamoDB example)

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-data-pipeline

I'm trying to run the S3->DynamoDB example and having some problems running the EMR cluster that is created for the `MyImportJob` activity.

We configured our IAM accounts such that every user can create EC2 machines with a specific 'team_id' tag (of his team). That helps us control the resources, prevent mistakes and monitor usage.

When Pipeline tries to launch the EMR cluster, it (probably) does it without the tags and therefore it fails with `Terminated with errors: User account is not authorized to call EC2`.  I tried to find a configuration in the EMRCluster resource but couldn't find anything that will help me set that. I'm pretty sure that it fails because of the tags policy.

Any idea how I can overcome this?
Does it help if If create a CloudFormation template for that? Do I have more control there? (I'm going to create the pipeline as a part of the application template anyway, just wanted to experience the product before).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a solution for how to add tags to EMR(and how to set it to be visible to all users) so I have created a python script to run as bootstrap action. If its still relevant you can find it [here](https://github.com/eIlluz/aws-fix-emr-vis-tags)